# Replace XML string using SQL Server Replace or CLR Regex?

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, clr, sql-server-2014

I have the following XML string:

```
<row>
  <id>
    <old></old>
    <new>2151</new>
  </id>
  <name>
    <old></old>
    <new>test</new>
  </name>
  <amount>
    <old></old>
    <new>62</new>
  </amount>
</row>
```

I need to parse and replace the string so that the end result will have the format:

```
columnname|oldvalue|newvalue^
```

Therefore the above example would look like this:

```
id||2151^name||test^amount||62^
```

The XML string will always contain one `row` node. The nodes within it (ig. id, name, amount, etc) will vary and it can range for a couple of nodes to over 100 nodes. The structure will however be always the same.

Is is possible to do it in SQL server directly or do I need to use a CLR function in order to use regular expressions?

The function must be generic because the column names will be different.

Comment: What if you have another row? It will be attached to first row or will separate? How many different nodes (id, name, amount) will be?

Comment: @Darka Edited my question to answer your questions.

Comment: Sql server vs clr ?? It depend upon real scenario.We can't say by just looking at 1 small sample data .If no.of column and no . of rows are less and not very frequently use then we can use below query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `local-name()` to retrieve a node's name:

```
select  col1.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') + '|' +
        col1.value('(./old)[1]', 'varchar(max)') + '|' +
        col1.value('(./new)[1]', 'varchar(max)') + '^'
from    @x.nodes('/row/*') as tbl(col1)

-->
id||2151^
name||test^
amount||62^
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/907/0)

Comment: select ','+ col1.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') + ' || ' +
        
        col1.value('(./new)[1]', 'varchar(max)') + ' ^ ' 
from    @xml.nodes('/row/*') as tbl(col1) for xml path('')

Answer (score 0):

This should do, if the pattern of the XML is just same and not going to change.

```
string checkStr1 = @"<row>
    <id>
    <old></old>
    <new>2151</new>
    </id>
    <name>
    <old></old>
    <new>test</new>
    </name>
    <amount>
    <old></old>
    <new>62</new>
    </amount>
</row>";
Regex r1 = new Regex(@"\<([a-z]+)\>(?:\t|\r|\n|\s)*\<old\>(.*?)\<\/old\>(?:\t|\r|\n|\s)*\<new\>(.*?)\<\/new\>(?:\t|\r|\n|\s)*</[a-z]+?>");
MessageBox.Show(r1.Replace(checkStr1, m => "^" + m.Groups[1].Value + "|" + m.Groups[2].Value + "|" + m.Groups[3].Value));
```

And finally replace the "row" opening and closing tags...

Hope this helps...

Comment: It is said, "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."  There are better ways to parse XML than [regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Hey Andomar, you are right about better ways for handling XML than regex. I used regex since Ivan or Darka was OK with regex.. Anyway thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Declare @xml xml='<row>
  <id>
    <old></old>
    <new>2151</new>
  </id>
  <name>
    <old></old>
    <new>test</new>
  </name>
  <amount>
    <old></old>
    <new>62</new>
  </amount>
</row>'


select 'id||'+  xmlData.Col.value('(./id)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')+'^' +
'name||'+ xmlData.Col.value('(./name)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')+'^' +
'amount||'+ xmlData.Col.value('(./amount)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')+'^'
from  @xml.nodes('//row') xmlData(Col)
```

Comment: The OP said the names of the XML nodes are not known beforehand. So there could be others than "id", "name", and "amount".

Comment: yeah,this is the drawback of my current query.Meanwhile I am thinking .

Comment: Yeah it's even in the title of his question :)